# Is is possible to format a disk to behave like a CD-R?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, fdisk, parted

**Is it possible to configure a partition/disk to have non-removable content like a CD-R?**

By this I mean

1. I can write on the partition/disk only on empty "parts"
2. The written content cannot be changed nor erased (become read-only once written)

I am obviously looking for another solution than create 2 separate partitions from the main one (the first is read-only and the second is read-write).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to leave the data as immutable, on a partition in linux file system.

You can make a data file immutable with the command chattr.

The operator **+** causes the selected attributes to be added to the existing attributes of the files.

The operator **-** causes them to be removed.

The operator **=** causes them to be the only attributes that the files have.

A file with an immutable attribute can not be:

```
Modified
Deleted
Renamed
No soft or hard link created by anyone including root user.
```

Only the root can set or clear this attribute.

How to make a file immutable on Linux

First, you need to login as root user.

```
exec sudo -i
```

Only root user can `set and remove` immutable flag on a file.

The syntax is:

```
chattr +i file
chattr +i /path/to/filename
```